# Amazon S3 image originals dead before certain date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got an issue with a legacy Amazon S3 setup. I'm not 100% sure of the particulars, so let me know what you need and I'll do my best to produce it.

We have a Basic plan with AWS S3 and are uploading images via CKEditor, which resizes the image to be hosted at different URLs. Everything has been working fine so far, but the urls of some of the images have started to fail:

```
src="app_production.s3.amazonaws.com/rich/rich_files/rich_files/1105/original/imagename.png"
```

whereas

```
src="app_production.s3.amazonaws.com/rich/rich_files/rich_files/1105/s1200/imagename.png"
```

is working as normal.

It seems as though when I look through my S3 buckets the "original" files have been changed to 0b. Why has this happened? And what can I do to fix it, short of going through each image and changing the URL?

EDIT: 
I've Accepted Johns answer, but I am still having this issue. He has identified the problem as coming from within my own App, but I'm not entirely sure what it is. I can't find a reason that our application would have pinged Amazon about images from 2 years ago. If anyone has Ideas, I'ld love to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not change the content of files. If the files are zero bytes long, it's because something is uploading them as an empty file.

Nor does S3 rename files, so again, whatever system you have uploading files is making everything the way it is.

(By the way, there is no "Basic plan" on AWS. Everyone has the same, fully-featured account.)

Comment: I tried to create a case in the AWS support center and was greeted with 
```Technical Support
Unavailable under the Basic Support Plan```

Comment: Could you possible point me in the direction of what might have changed? We've been relying on those urls for 2 years and now all of a sudden the file doesn't exist?

Comment: Ah! The _Basic Support Plan_ — I thought you were referring to the AWS Account itself. No, I can't point you to what might have changed, because it is _your_ software that made the change. Things only change on AWS if a person/application calls the system and uploads/deletes things. You should debug your existing application.

Comment: My mistake, I thought they were one and the same.

Comment: Yes, FYI technical support is an optional extra. If you do not elect to have support ('Basic Support Plan'), you can ask questions on forums but there is no guaranteed support. If you sign up for _Developer_ or _Business_ support, you can open support cases. The choice of support plan does not impact your actual use of AWS (aside from the additional charge for support).